# vue-router - How to get previous page url?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to get previous page link or url in `vue-router`. Like a this. How to do it?

```
const link = this.$router.getPrevLink(); // function is not exist?
this.$router.push(link);
```

Near concept is `this.$router.go(-1)`.

```
this.$router.go(-1);
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

All of vue-router's [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) receive the previous route as a `from` argument ..

> Every guard function receives three arguments:
>
> - `to: Route`: the target Route Object being navigated to.
> - **`from: Route`: the current route being navigated away from.**
> - `next: Function`: this function must be called to resolve the hook. The
>     action depends on the arguments provided to next

As an example you could use `beforeRouteEnter`, an in-component navigation guard, to get the previous route and store it in your data ..

```
...
data() {
 return {
   ...
   prevRoute: null
 }
},
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    vm.prevRoute = from
  })
},
...
```

Then you can use `this.prevRoute.path` to get the previous URL.

Comment: **Note**: That you can only use `beforeRouteEnter` in the component that the route is defined for and not a child component which is not defined in the router.

Comment: @hitautodestruct Then adding it as a global mixin wouldn't be a good idea since components that don't have a route would mess up ?!

Comment: @Husam Ibrahim Also what is the advantage of this method compared to the `.go(-1)` ?

Comment: @Ibris The OP asked for a way to get the URL of the previous page (I don't know the details of their use case). If you simply want to go to the previous page then `this.$router.go(-1)` is the way to go ;)

Comment: Say I directly navigate to the SPA by copying and pasting the link in the browser, `this.$router.go(-1)` is not suitable in this case.

Comment: This does not work for me, I get the **error message**: `[Vue warn]: Error in the mounted hook:" TypeError: this.prevRoute is null "` when trying to get `this.prevRoute.path` from the console. Confusing is the fact that `console.log (this)` correctly displays `prevRoute`. @HusamIbrahim

Comment: @Tenarius Seems that this is the expected behavior because `next` callbacks are invoked after a `nextTick`. So you can't access properties set by the callback in `created`/`mounted` because these hooks come earlier. See [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1144).

Comment: is there `beforeRouteEnter` in Vue 3?

Answer (score 43):

For Vue 3 with Vue Router 4, my solution was:

```
this.$router.options.history.state.back
```

The final code:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Error404',
  data () {
    return {
      lastPath: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.lastPath = this.$router.options.history.state.back
  },
  computed: {
    prevRoutePatch () {
      return this.lastPath ? this.lastPath : '/dashboard'
    }
  }
})
```

Regards.

Comment: For Vuejs 3, First `import { useRouter } from "vue-router";` Second invoke the `router` instance `const router = useRouter();` then for example: `router.options.history.state.back ` works like cake!

Comment: vue-router v4.0.16: `router.options.history.state['back']`

Answer (score 6):

Though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53789212/9764426) is great, *the received route wouldn't always be the route before in history* in case of popstate navigations (aka when the user clicks the back button).

So **if you use Vuex** here's a code snippet that respects this behavior:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    routerHistory: [],
  },
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    const fromHistory = Boolean(savedPosition);

    if (fromHistory && store.state.routerHistory.length > 0) {
      store.state.routerHistory.splice(-1, 1);
    } else {
      store.state.routerHistory.push(from);
    }

    return savedPosition || { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
});
```

Once implemented, you can define a getter for the previous route inside your store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  getters: {
    previousRoute: (state) => {
      const historyLen = state.routerHistory.length;
      if (historyLen == 0) return null;
      return state.routerHistory[historyLen - 1];
    },
  },
});
```

This code uses the scrollBehavior hook, which only receives the savedPosition argument if it was a popstate navigation.
Thanks to Vuex we can then store all the routes in an array (over multiple pages).

Answer (score 6):

This routing solution will fall back to a static url if a previous url does not exist.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-link :to="prevRoutePath">Previous Page</router-link>
        <router-link to="/">Home Page</router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            vm.prevRoute = from;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        prevRoutePath() {return this.prevRoute ? this.prevRoute.path : '/'},
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-link :to="previousPage">Previous Page</router-link>
        <router-link to="/">Home Page</router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
    import { computed } from 'vue';

    const router = useRouter();

    const previousPage = computed(() => {
        const lastPath = router.options.history.state.back;
        return lastPath ? lastPath : '/';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To yank it right out of the $router object, use this in your computed or methods:

```
lastRouteName: function() {
  let returnVal = '';

  const routerStack = this.$router.history.stack;
  const idx = this.$router.history.index;

  if (idx > 0) {
    returnVal = routerStack[idx - 1].name;
  }

  return returnVal;
}
```

That'll return the route name, but you can also return the `.path` or whatever other property if you like.

To inspect the history object, do `console.log(this.$router.history);`

Comment: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'VueRouter'

Comment: Most likely this only works for VueRouter 4.

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 2.6 that works for me:

In-App.vue component when you initialize the VueRouter you can get from and to details as below:

```
export const globalState = Vue.observable({ from: {}, to: {} });
const router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/',
    routes: routes,
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        Vue.set(globalState, 'from', from);
        Vue.set(globalState, 'to', to);
        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    },
});
```

routes are ur routes and each time u navigate to a different URL you will have all from and to routes details.
Then u can import the `globalState` object and use it like that

```
     import { globalState } from './app';
     goBack() {
        const lastPath = globalState.from?.fullPath;
        const currentPath = globalState.to?.fullPath;
        if (lastPath && currentPath !== lastPath) 
           {
              this.$router.push(lastPath);
           } else {
              this.$router.push('another-path');
            }
        }
```