# How does the next() guard function in vue-router work?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to understand the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53789212/7489488). The solution allows the user to keep track of the previous route in the current route.

Below is the snippet of Vue code that I'm trying to understand. If I understand correctly, `next` accepts a callback function that receives the current component's vue instance. We then set the `prevRoute` data property of this vue instance to `from`. Is this interpretation correct? If not, what is actually happening?

If someone could also add a brief explanation as to what the Vue API is doing behind the scenes that would also be very helpful for me to actually understand the snippet of code.

```
...
data() {
 return {
   ...
   prevRoute: null
 }
},
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    vm.prevRoute = from
  })
},
...
```

Comment: A pointer to reference vue-router [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/dist/vue-router.js#L2224): Guard beforeRouteEnter seems implemented as a templated NavigationGuard object (see \types\vue.d.ts). For a deeper dive start at function extractEnterGuards(...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)...

> The `beforeRouteEnter` guard does **NOT** have access to `this`, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.
>
> However, you can access the instance by passing a callback to `next`. The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed, and the component instance will be passed to the callback as the argument

So `vm` is the component instance assigned to the destination route.

---

From your question...

> We then set the `prevRoute` *data property* of this vue instance to from. Is this interpretation correct?

Almost. All you're doing is setting a direct object property on the Vue component which is after all, just a JavaScript object at heart. For example

```js
const vm = { name: 'I am totally a Vue component' }
vm.prevRoute = from
```

This property will not be reactive but you can certainly access it within your component via `this`, just as you can other non-data properties like `$el`, `$refs`, etc.