# How to get router name of history router

Tags: vue.js

I want to go back by using this.$router.go(-n).
And I want to check the name of the back router to decided to go back or not.
How can I get the name of back router?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788975/vue-router-how-to-get-previous-page-url

Comment: That is not the answer I want.It just gets the name of this.$router.go(-1) from 'from'. I wanna get the name of this.$router.go(-n) like this.$router.go(-2), this.$router.go(-3) ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use beforeRouteEnter

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    vm.prevRoute = from
  })
},
```

and in paramater **from** you will get previous route.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it just gets previous route. I mean get the route of n (2,3...) step back.